# Using WaitHandle

Tags: c#, autoresetevent, waithandle, manualresetevent

I'm trying to do something like this:

```
EventWaitHandle handler = new EventWaitHandle(false, EventResetMode.AutoReset)

//This code will run in background thread
private void AsyncWait() {
    while (true) {
        handler.WaitOne();
        //LongRunningOperation()
    }
}
```

Elsewhere in the code, there will be methods that call:

```
handler.Set()
```

So the LongRunningOperation() is executed..

Problem is, the `handler.Set()` can be called again while the `AsyncWait()` thread is running the `LongRunningOperation()`

This makes the `LongRunningOperation()` will never be called whenever the `handler.Set()` is called while `AsyncWait()` is still executing `LongRunningOperation()`

How to make this right? :(

Comment: If you called `handler.Set()`, `handler.Set()`, `handler.WaitOne()`, `handler.WaitOne()` are you wanting the last `WaitOne()` to not block because `Set` was called twice before?

Comment: @Scott Chamberlain, exactly

Comment: You are using `EventResetMode.AutoReset` so even when `LongRunningOperation()` is running the `handler` was already (automatically) reset, so when you call `handler.Set()` during the `LongRunningOperation()`, it won't cause the next `handler.WaitOne();` to block as it was already reset directly after waiting for it. So either there is no problem or either I think I don't see your problem clearly...

Comment: @Stormenet No, the next  handler.WaitOne()  will block.

Comment: It shouldn't, see the following example (create standard windows forms project and replace Form1 code): http://pastebin.com/bCqYdpSm 
For me it outputs `Pass: 1
Pass: 2`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a Semaphore instead of AutoResetEvent.

A semaphore uses a counter internally. You can also define the maximum number of threads that can be "let through" at a time.

```
readonly Semaphore _semaphore = new Semaphore(0, int.MaxValue);

public void Enqueue<T>(T item)
{
     _internalQueue.Enqueue(item);
     _semaphore.Release();  // Informs that deque task to unblock if waiting. Equivalent to the  WaitHandle.Set() method. Increases the semaphore counter
}

public T Dequeue()
{
     _semaphore.WaitOne();   // Blocks as long as there are no items in the queue. Decreases the semaphore counter when "let through". Blocks the thread as long as semaphore counter is zero.
     return _internalQueue.Dequeue();
}
```

Comment: Feels like a solution. I need to take more tests to verify and set this as an answer.

Comment: @ch0eb1t It [behaves just like the example](http://ideone.com/1ihumh) I posted in the comments to your question